# How to link a Google Analytics "contact us" event with a later event when they become a customer from a custom URL sent to them?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have people filing in a Wufoo contact us form on our site. After communication, some people become customers by checking out using a custom URL we email to them. We would like to link these two events (form completion and sale) so that our e-commerce tracking on Google Analytics connects the first entry to the conversion. How do we go about doing this?

We can have the Wufoo ID showing as a custom variable on the thank you page and put the same id in the conversion page but not sure how to technically link them.

Comment: Universal or asynchronous analytics ?